# Eliminar borde Preferencefragment al realizar inflate - Android

Tags: android, layout, sharedpreferences

Estoy teniendo un problema con una app que estoy desarrollando.

Me he dado cuenta que una pantalla no se pinta bien por debajo de determinada API

Os pongo el código y unas capturas.

Se trata de la sección de preferencias.
La estoy haciendo con el wizard de Android studio, me ha creado una clase abstracta:
AppCompatPreferecteActivity, os la dejo aquí por si os hace falta mirarla:

```
public abstract class AppCompatPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDelegate().installViewFactory();
    getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getDelegate().onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
    return getDelegate().getSupportActionBar();
}

public void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar) {
    getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
    return getDelegate().getMenuInflater();
}

@Override
public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(view);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(view, params);
}

@Override
public void addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    getDelegate().addContentView(view, params);
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    getDelegate().onPostResume();
}

@Override
protected void onTitleChanged(CharSequence title, int color) {
    super.onTitleChanged(title, color);
    getDelegate().setTitle(title);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    getDelegate().onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    getDelegate().onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getDelegate().onDestroy();
}

public void invalidateOptionsMenu() {
    getDelegate().invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
    if (mDelegate == null) {
        mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
    }
    return mDelegate;
}
}
```

Por otro lado luego se crea la clase en cuestión:

public class ConfigSettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
    /**
     * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
     * to reflect its new value.
     */
    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            String stringValue = value.toString();

```
        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference.setSummary(
                    index >= 0
                            ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);

        } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
            // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
            // using RingtoneManager.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);

            } else {
                Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                        preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                if (ringtone == null) {
                    // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                    preference.setSummary(null);
                } else {
                    // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                    // name.
                    String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                    preference.setSummary(name);
                }
            }

        } else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }
};

/**
 * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
 * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
 */
private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
}

/**
 * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
 * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
 * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
 * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
 * dependent on the type of preference.
 *
 * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
 */
private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
    return isXLargeTablet(this);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
@TARgetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    setContentView(R.layout.config_custom);

}

@Override
public void onHeaderClick(Header header, int position) {
    super.onHeaderClick(header, position);
    if (header.id == R.id.logoutpref) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setMessage(R.string.msg_logout);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                MyConfig conf = new MyConfig(getApplicationContext());
                conf.setResortUserId(-1);
                conf.setStatusUser(0);
                //action on dialog close
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginActivity.class)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));

                finish();
            }

        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });

        builder.show();


    }
}

/**
 * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
 * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
 */
protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
    return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || CommsPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || VisibilityPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || SecurityPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
}

/**
 * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TARgetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class CommsPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_comms);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.config_custom, null);

    }

}
```

}

El problema viene en el PreferenceFragment

En las ultimas API me sale bien, el problema es cuando empiezo a bajar, mirad la diferencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me mete unos bordes a la derecha y la izquierda :-SS al cargar con el inflate el layout :-S
 ¿A que se debe? He probado de todo y no doy con la solución :-(

Gracias

Dejo los layout por si quereis verlos, pero no tienen nada raro:
 config_custom: http://codepaste.net/eyfj8m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He conseguido solucionarlo, lo dejo por aquí.
Aunque sigo desconociendo el motivo de porque está pasando.

Tan solo había que añadir esto en los PreferentFragment:

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.config_custom, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        View container_parent = (View)view.getParent();
        container_parent.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    }
```